# circle-color by date in mapbox gl js ?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to style some circles with a geojson property of date (format "YYYY-MM-DD") and circle-color expression. I do not want something complicated and try things like:

```
'circle-color': ["case",[">=",["to-number",["get","date"]],["to-number","2017-12-31"]],"black","red"]
```

But it seems far more complicated as it does not work. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the result of the `to-number('YYYY-MM-DD)` function will be the NaN.

So either store the date values in the time-stamp, or just compare them as strings:

```
'circle-color': ["case", [">=", 
    ["to-string", ["get", "date"]],
    ["to-string", "2017-12-31"]
], "black", "red"]
```

- https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-types-to-number
- http://jsfiddle.net/du9wf3Lq/

Comment: thank you. i found another way to get a number with applying a function to each data.feature comparing the date to 2017-12-31 (calculating the number of days between dates)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest working with integers as I think you realised.  You can convert the dates into integers; for example by calculating a date difference.  For example if pulling the date data from PostgreSQL you could do something like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM now()-lr.dated) AS datediff
```

Once you have these integer values you can get a color scale from a [color palette helper](https://gka.github.io/palettes/#/9%7Cs%7C00429d,96ffea,ffffe0%7Cffffe0,ff005e,93003a%7C1%7C1) color palette helper, copy paste your hex values and mapbox will interpolate from the values.  For example:

```
"paint": {
  'circle-color': [
    'interpolate',
    ['linear'],
    ["to-number",['get','datediff']],
    0,'#00429d',
    100,'#2e59a8',
    200,'#4771b2',
    300,'#5d8abd',
    400,'#73a2c6',
    500,'#8abccf',
    600,'#a5d5d8',
    700,'#c5eddf',
    800,'#ffffe0'
  ]
```